# Mongoose/MongoDB: Increment value in a nested array

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a list of investors, and with every person, we store which companies they have shares in and how much:

```
"investors": [
  {
    "userID": 0,
    "investments": [
      {
        "company": "Google",
        "shares": 3
      },
      {
        "company": "Amazon",
        "shares": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So in this example, the person with the ID of 0 has 3 shares in Google, and 5 shares in Amazon. I'm trying to write a mongoose request that I could use to add new shares to an investor, whether it's a new company or not. So far my best attempt has been this:

```
Investor.updateOne(
  { 0 },
  // newInvestments is an array that contains all new investments that should be added to the database
  { userID: 0, $set: { investments: newInvestments } },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

This works fine when it comes to adding a new company, but with companies that the user already has shares in, the old value gets overridden by the new one. So for example, if the person buys 2 more shares in Google, we would want their shares to increase to 5, but this way it would just get overridden by 2.

I believe what I'm trying to achieve could be done using [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#-inc), but I'm not able to figure out the syntax in this specific scenario. I'm fairly new to MongoDB - any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: `$inc` could be a great option. What were the `$inc` queries you tried and what were the results?

Comment: I don't know how I could incorporate it in my existing code. My issue is that newInvestments is an array of objects and I would only need to increment a specific field in them (shares), so if I replace $set with $inc, that doesn't work.

Comment: Replacing it will not be enough. You would need to target the nested item. There are variety of ways including [function](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/function/?_ga=2.93454045.1399890031.1643643947-2047481517.1636044719) or [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)

Comment: I'm really confused about the usage of these, sorry. I tried "{ userId: 0, $addToSet: {investments: {$inc: newInvestments.shares}}}" as my second parameter, but it didn't work (nor did I expect it to, the documentation doesn't really elaborate on my use case at all).

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple using javascript:

1. find the document
2. use js to `push` the new investment or increment `shares` if it exists
3. call `doc.save()`

```
const investor = await Investor.findById(0);
newInvestments.forEach(newInv => {
  const index = investor.investments.findIndex(inv => inv.company === newInv.company);
  if(index === -1) {
    investor.investments.push(newInv);
  } else {
    investor.investments[index].shares += newInv.shares;
  }
});
investor.save()
```